# Unable to run SVC no errors but it just stuck, any way to have a time out?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hyperopt

Unable to run code at the fit of SVC don't know what is causing the problem looking for a solution to fit in SVC with no hang or a way to time out and skip.
if i do more evaluation the more likely it will hang.
I have to restart Jupyter notebook kernel to run the code again.

```
    def objective_func_svc(args):


        if args['model']==SVC:
            C = args['param']['C']
            kernel = args['param']['kernel']
            clf = SVC(C=C,kernel=kernel,gamma='auto')

        clf.fit(X_train,y_train)   

        loss =1-clf.score(X_train,y_train)  
        return loss

    space_svc = hp.choice('classifier',[

            {'model': SVC,
            'param':{'C':hp.lognormal('C',0.0,1),
            'kernel':hp.choice('kernel',['poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid'])}}])
```

---

```
        print('\nKernel + C choice Score') 

        best_classifier = fmin(objective_func_svc,space_svc,algo=algoused,max_evals=max_evals)

        if best_classifier.get('kernel')==0:
            kernel='poly'
        elif best_classifier.get('kernel')==1:
            kernel='rbf'
        elif best_classifier.get('kernel')==2:
            kernel='sigmoid'

        clf = SVC(C=best_classifier.get("C"),kernel=kernel,gamma='auto')

        print('\nC=',best_classifier.get("C"))
        print('kernel=',kernel)
        print('\nBest_classifier Score ')  
        clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
        y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)
        clf.score(X_test,y_test)

        a,p,n=print_confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```